# stop textmate from reloading a file

Tags: textmate

I asked Textmate to load something much too large for it and then forced the application to quit. Now, when I reopen TextMate, it keeps trying to load that file and consequently can't open.

**How do I reset the state of Textmate, so that it won't try to open this file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am not sure of the older versions but latest version of Mate has an option skip restoring of old files on reopen by holding the **Shift** button.

You can enable that feature in preferences under **At startup**

[image]

When you hold **Shift** you'll get an alert like this, which will help you skip reopening of large files.

[image]

I hope you already found this solution on your own.